# Model store edmx file doesnt get generated in debug mode but does in release mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, ef-code-first, edmx

Is there anyway for my edmx file to get generated in debug mode instead of release mode?

```
public class DatabaseConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public DatabaseConfiguration() : base()
        {
            var modelStoreLocation = Config.Data.ModelStoreLocation;
            if (!modelStoreLocation.IsBlank())
            {
                var cachedDbModelStore = new MyDbModelStore(Config.Data.ModelStoreLocation);
                var dependencyResolver = new SingletonDependencyResolver<DbModelStore>(cachedDbModelStore);
                AddDependencyResolver(dependencyResolver);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is not building properly .So when you generate in release mode it works
Build solution properly then it will work  in debug mode too.

Comment: This is not an answer.  Do you really think its not building right when I have BUILT it in debug mode?

Comment: The info you gave is too little . Can you place solution in  a GitHub Private repository and add me  tjitender@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanting to load two different edmx files, one for debug and one for release you can use the compilation directives.

```
#if DEBUG
var modelStoreLocation = [Debug ModelStoreLocation];
#endif
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Though I am not sure I would advise using different models.  It's wrapped in bad karma.

Comment: No I am saying that my edmx never gets created in debug mode, only in release.